# How to share picture or post via PHP SDK similar to a facebook share button?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, sdk, share

I want to Share Photos  on my profile when I post photo on my facebook page.
**how can I do this with php sdk  ?**

Similar to the share link shown in this picture
http://g1303.hizliresim.com/17/8/kusyg.png